# How do I change the submission button text?

Tags: 8

I am using the beta release of the [OpenID Connect](https://www.drupal.org/project/openid_connect) module, and I encounter a feature issue in the code.

My goal is to display a simple login label of the block rather than using the default provided by the module. To explain, in line #92 of the file [src/Form/LoginForm.php](https://cgit.drupalcode.org/openid_connect/tree/src/Form/OpenIDConnectLoginForm.php?h=8.x-1.x#n92), #value is defined as

```
'#value' => t('Log in with @client_title', [
  '@client_title' => $client['label'],
]),
```

but I want to make it simplier, just `#value' => t('Log in),`

Is there any way to create and apply patch for beta release or other workaround how this can be handled? (Not hardcoding in the file itself)

The actual block displays the following.

> [image]

What I want to show is the following.

> [image]

How do I change the submission button text?

Comment: Just use hook_form_alter for such a small change, no need to involve patches

Comment: I havent yet tried doing such but Ill try. I would appreciate if you can give me a working example of a simple hook_form_alter? Thanks!

Comment: drupal.org is your friend ;) https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Form%21form.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/8.5.x

Comment: Thanks guys for your response. Updated my issue. Added an actual code implemented. I havent yet made a working hook implementation but I tried to just log values.